# How to sum value ​for a specific field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I have the following situation

```
Sottocategoria | Quantità
type_1         |  100.00
type_2         |  100.00
type_1         |  100.00
```

I would to obtain a new table that give me the following view:

```
Sottocategoria | Quantità
type_1         |  200.00
type_2         |  100.00
```

here my  models.py with "quantita" and "sottocategoria" fields' situation:

```
class Tipologia(models.Model):
    nome= models.CharField('Categoria', max_length=30)

class Sottocategoria(models.Model):
    tipologia = models.ForeignKey(Tipologia, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField( max_length=30)

class Materiale(models.Model):
    conto = models.CharField('Conto', max_length=30, choices=(
            ('MATERIA PRIMA', 'MATERIA PRIMA'),
            ('SUSSIDIARIA', 'SUSSIDIARIA'),
        ))
    tipologia = models.ForeignKey(Tipologia, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    sottocategoria = models.ForeignKey(Sottocategoria, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantita=models.DecimalField('Quantità',max_digits=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the `Sottocategoria` objects with the sum of the `quantita`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Sottocategoria.objects.annotate(
    quantita=Sum('meteriale__quantita')
)
```

the `Sottocategoria` objects that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.quantita` that contains the sum of the `quantita` of the related `Materiale` objects.

You can thus use this query in views where you need the total `quantita`, and then for example render it in the templates with `{{ mysottocategoria.quantita }}`.

If you need this often, you can use a *manager* for that:

```
class SottocategoriaManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        super().get_queryset().annotate(
            quantita=Sum('meteriale__quantita')
        )

class Sottocategoria(models.Model):
    # …

    objects = SottocategoriaManager()
```

Now each time you access `Sottocategoria.objects`, it will thus return an annotated queryset.

One can use a [**`Coalesce`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) to replace `NULL` with `0` if there are no related `meteriale`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Sottocategoria.objects.annotate(
    quantita=Coalesce(Sum('meteriale__quantita'), Value(0))
)
```

You can implement this in the manager if you need to often as specified before.

Comment: thanks very much, but where should I add this code? In views or models? Becouse this values I have to use it in other views and in other apps of my project

Comment: You'll have to most likely call it in all individual views that way

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco: in the views where you need it, or you can write a manager (see edit) if you need this often.

Answer (score 0):

In my views I add this code:

```
def magazzino(request):
    elements = Materiale.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = MaterialeForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             print("Il form è valido")
             new_input = form.save()

    else :
        form = MaterialeForm()
        elements = Materiale.objects.all()

    agg=Sottocategoria.objects.annotate(quantita=Sum('materiale__quantita'))

    context= {
        "form": form,
        'elements':elements,
        'agg' : agg,

            }
    return render(request, "magazzino/magazzino.html", context)
```

and in my templates:

```
{% for e in agg %}
          <tr>
              <td> {{e.name}} </td>
              <td> {{e.tipologia}} </td>
              <td> {{e.quantita}} </td>
              {% endfor %}
          </tr>
```

is it correct? Works but I don't now if my code following the DRY principles. Another questions: It's possibile to replace the result "None" with zero?

Thanks